# For Better response time-Map loading

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to develop an application using OL. In my code I am using base maps of google , yahoo etc. For this I am  including the link in the script,this means that I am connecting to respective server(google,yahoo) etc every time through internet connection(I think this is what including the links in scripts mean). But sometimes when I select Yahoo maps , it takes a lot of time to load and in some cases it doesn't load at all.  So for a better response time my idea is to use caching concept and store these maps in my memory using cookies etc.... But I donno whether Its possible to do this or not.So will this caching concept work?

Are there any other better ways to get good response time with loading of maps???? or How can I load maps better?
Your suggestion are much valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better option for cache is use OpenStreet Map as your default map and which much compare to Google Street Maps and you can download the country specific data or world map data and hosted in your mapping server (for example GeoServer), then it allow you to cache the tile as provide better response time for users.

Other option would be if you can use/purchase Google Enterprise API license which allows to handle much response time than default one.

Reference : 
Data download:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Downloading
 http://downloads.cloudmade.com/

GeoServer : http://www.geoserver.org

Answer (score 3):

The Yahoo, Google, and other commercial layer content is hosted by those providers, and access to it is through a closed API  that restricts your ability to use those images outside of the API. There is no way within the terms of service for you to capture these images in cache or anything else like that beyond what the user's browser already does.

Comment: So in that case can we opt for purchasing the maps??? does this help in terms of better response time  issues??? I mean do we still need to connect to google or yahoo server, even though we buy maps from them..... as of what I heard is , even if we buy them we will be getting just additional facilities in the map but should be connected to that server... I donno if this is true

Comment: Google Static Maps Terms Changed on 8th April 2011 - you can access the tiles outside the API now. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html